# F# chart control change legend text

Tags: .net, f#, mschart

when using [F# chart control library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2011/04/01/fsharpchart-wrapping-the-system-windows-forms-datavisualization-charting-charting-types.aspx), how can I specify the text of the legend? 
for instance:

```
    FSharpChart.Line [ for f in 0.0 .. 0.1 .. 10.0 -> cos f ] 
   |> FSharpChart.WithLegend()
```

shows a legend with text "GenericChart_Series_1". How can I change the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the legend using the `Name` property of the chart object. The property can be set when calling the `Line` member:

```
FSharpChart.Line([ for f in 0.0 .. 0.1 .. 10.0 -> cos f ], Name = "Cos")
|> FSharpChart.WithLegend()
```